# GSettings key hi-dpi-factor not found in schema

Tags: gnome, gsettings, hdpi

I am almost a beginner to ubuntu. I installed a "netspeed" extension using the guide from here [ubuntuhandbook](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/06/download-upload-speed-ubuntu-20-04-panel/). Its working fine but when I open gnome-tweaks to configure its settings, it shows me the error

```
The settings of extension netspeed@hedayaty.gmail.com had an error:

Error: GSettings key hi-dpi-factor not found in schema org.gnome.shell.extensions.netspeed

Stack trace:

Error: GSettings key hi-dpi-factor not found in schema org.gnome.shell.extensions.netspeed

Stack trace:
  _checkKey@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js:576:23
  _init/createCheckedMethod/<@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js:528:30
  NetSpeed_App@/home/tayyab/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/netspeed@hedayaty.gmail.com/prefs.js:171:31
  buildPrefsWidget@/home/tayyab/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/netspeed@hedayaty.gmail.com/prefs.js:272:18
  _init@resource:///org/gnome/Shell/Extensions/js/extensionsService.js:207:40
  OpenExtensionPrefsAsync/<@resource:///org/gnome/Shell/Extensions/js/extensionsService.js:122:28
  asyncCallback@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js:132:13
  run@resource:///org/gnome/Shell/Extensions/js/dbusService.js:175:20
  main@resource:///org/gnome/Shell/Extensions/js/main.js:19:13
  run@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/script/package.js:222:19
  start@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/script/package.js:206:5
  @/usr/share/gnome-shell/org.gnome.Shell.Extensions:1:17
```

Comment: What OS & release are you using?  (the link you provided assumes 20.04, is that what you're using)

Comment: yup, its ubuntu 20.04